# Comparing package-based and traditional character generation in Eclipse Phase

Tags: eclipse-phase

*Transhuman* has introduced an alternative, package-based character generation for EP. It features a sidebar on the topic on page 13:

> Note that this package system builds characters that are worth 1,100 CP. This is ~20 CP more than characters built using the system in the EP Core Rulebook.

(CP = Customization Points).

I've tried tallying up the systems, and that's not the results I get.

**Package System:**

- 105 points of aptitudes (free)
- Native tongue at 70+Int (free)
- 10 Package Points (worth 1000 CP)
- 100 CP to spend on morph, equipment and customization.

1100 CP total, as stated.

**Traditional System:**

- 105 points of aptitudes (free)
- Native tongue at 70+Int (free)
- 1000 CP
- Background (varies, but 40 CP is the baseline)
- Faction (again, 40 is the baseline)
- 1 Moxie (15 CP)
- 5,000 credits (5 CP)
- 50 rep (5 CP)

For a total of 1105 CP, not 1080 as the sidebar suggests. It appears that the last three bits that "traditional" characters get for free, 1 Moxie, 5000 credits and 50 rep, have been lost in transition. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: went and got the books to back up my answer, which turns out is mostly right - go common sense, costs a lot less!

The Eclipse Phase core book is being offered as [a free download (?) at this blog](http://robboyle.wordpress.com/eclipse-phase-pdfs/).

> Eclipse Phase, character generation, p. 130, step 4 (break out box in top right corner of page):
>
> "Spend Free Points (p. 134)
>   a) 105 aptitude points
>   **b) 1 Moxie
>   c) 5,000 credit
>   d) 50 Rep**
>   e) Native tongue"

So:

> If you don't factor in the "free" items [in the traditional system] as having a cost [in the traditional system], it reduces the cost down to 1,080 CP as stated;

[snip rest of paragraph]

> So, to paraphrase your OP:

[Snip out Package System]

> **Traditional System:**
>
> - 105 points of aptitudes (free)
>
>   - Native tongue at 70+Int (free)
>   - 1000 CP
>   - Background (varies, but 40 CP is the baseline)
>   - Faction (again, 40 is the baseline)
>   - 1 Moxie (free)
>   - 5,000 credits (free)
>   - 50 rep (free)
>
> Hope that helps?

As regards the free moxie and rep, they're included in the packages to what seems like overflowing, so it appears to be that as long as you fill out your 10 PP sensibly you've got them through the packages anyway (i.e. you buy a 5PP, 3PP and 2x 1PP in any combination and you'll get a minimum of one moxie and 50 rep). For credits, they're included in the value of the additional 100 CP you get to spend on gear and equipment.

Would like to think this answers the question (in pretty much the same way it did before), with the references everybody desperately needs.

If you need more explicit answers, you're going to have to read the Transhuman book a little closer and look at how the package system provides the free stuff within the package awards and additional CP resulting from the Package system.

Comment: If you don't have the rules nor have experience to Back It Up! Don't answer the question.

Comment: I don't have the rules, but I have experience of converting characters between systems and comparing different character build mechanics within systems (i.e. D&Ds different dice-roll systems vs. point-buy system, BRPs similar dice roll vs. point systems etc.), so thought I might help with providing some viewpoint to this (up until now) unanswered question. Apologies if I thought having some kind of answer might be better than none at all.

Comment: Also, the [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective/Back It Up](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) article for StackExchange only references good _questions_, so didn't think that answers, no matter how tangentially relevant and capable of answering the question in a broad sense, were under the same purview.

Comment: "Back It Up! means that your answers must be based on either: Something that happened to you personally; Something you can back up with a reference. They talk about how 'opinion, by itself, is noise.' "

Comment: Went and got the book, edited my (as it turns out, pretty bang on) answer with a tidy up, a reference to the Character Creation process and a brief talk about the package system (which is pretty much too large a concept to actually discuss within a single answer).

Comment: Except they are not free! Or, rather, they contribute to the "value" of a character, just like "free" background and faction does. While packages provide moxie and rep and skills a background would have given, they are paid for from the package budget of 100cp. Language and aptitudes could also be counted towards the "value" of a character, but they are universal among both systems and so can be discounted, unlike moxie, rep and creds. You appear to be making the same mistake writers made, or, at least, missing the actual reason for those numbers, if there is one.

Comment: I think you're being rather selective as to what you want and don't want to include in the cost/value/"calculation of any kind", as when following the rulebook and considering "free" aspects as "free" the calculations work. The packages (bar a few) include Moxie and rep as incorporated additions, and you can still buy more with the CP you get to spend after purchasing packages;  it could be argued that you can get more moxie and rep for free as part of the package system, e.g. you can pick 2x 3PP packages with 1x moxie/50x rep in each before you think about spending CP to buy more.

Comment: Fundamentally, the question is simple: given that everything has a CP cost, CP value of a character can be calculated based on their sheet. *Transhuman* explicitly states it produces characters that are worth ~20 CP more than the core book. I don't see how that is the case. Semantics of what's "free" or not don't matter. Final character sheet is what matters.

Comment: I can only suggest getting in touch with the creators of Transhuman for clarification then.